# Integration using trigonometric substitutions makes the working very complicated.

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int y^2\ \sqrt{4y^2+1}$ ${dy}$ 
I couldn't figure this one out. I used trigonometric substitution.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int y^2\sqrt{4y^2+1}dy$$
Apply Trig substitution :$y=\dfrac12\tan u$ and you get
$$=\int\dfrac18\sec^3 u\tan^2 udu$$
$$=\int\dfrac18\sec^3 u(\sec^2u-1)du$$
$$=\dfrac18\int (\sec^5 u-\sec^3 u)du$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: That's where i got to, I even got an answer for that. But when I plug in the limits the final answer is wrong. the answer is supposed to be 0.6063. I got 0.3773. The upper limit is 1 and lower is 0.

Comment: @MaizHalyym Where are the limit bounds in your question?

Comment: I may be missing something but to me $$\sec^3u(sec^2u-1)=sec^5u-sec^3u$$ rather than $$sec^5u+sec^3u$$...

Comment: @RhysHughes Fixed!

Comment: @MaizHalyym I checked this by calculator and it is fine. You have: $$\int_{0}^{\arctan(2)}{sec^5(u)-sec^3(u) du}$$ Use that $$\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}{sec^n(u) du}=\frac{\sec^{n-1}(u)\sin (u)}{n-1}+\frac{n-2}{n-1}\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}{sec^{n-2}(u) du}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{d(x(x^2+a^2)^n)}{dx}=(x^2+a^2)^n+2nx^2(x^2+a^2)^{n-1}$$

$$=(x^2+a^2)^n+2n(x^2+a^2-a^2)(x^2+a^2)^{n-1}=(x^2+a^2)^n(1+2n)-2na^2(x^2+a^2)^{n-1}$$

Integrating both sides $$x(x^2+a^2)^n=(2n+1)I_n-2na^2I_{n-1}$$

Now $$\int y^2(4y^2+1)^{1/2}dy=\dfrac14\int(4y^2+1)^{3/2}dy-\dfrac14\int(4y^2+1)^{1/2}dy$$

Here $n=\dfrac32$

Now use $\#8$ of [this](http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ11/integ11.html)

Answer (score 0):

use the so-called Euler Substitution, Substitute
$$\sqrt{4y^2+1}=2y+t$$ then we get

$$\frac{1-t^2}{4t}=y$$

$$dy=-\frac{t^2+1}{4t^2}dt$$

Answer (score 0):

An alternative substitution is $y:=\frac{1}{2}\sinh t$ so your integral is $$\int\frac{1}{8}\sinh^2t\cosh^2tdt=\int\frac{1}{32}\sinh^2 2tdt=\int\frac{1+\cosh 4t}{64}dt=\frac{t+\frac{1}{4}\sinh 4t}{64}+C=\frac{t+\sinh t\cosh t\cosh 2t}{64}+C=\frac{\operatorname{arsinh} 2y+2y\sqrt{1+4y^2}(8y^2-1)}{64}+C.$$